# Java: Passing a comparator to my implementation of qsort

Tags: java, generics, comparator, qsort

I'm writing a sorting method that works on a binary file.
(All actions done inside the file without reading the WHOLE file to the memory).

I get a:
"The method compare(E, E) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (so, so)"
from the qsort method.

Can you see why?

Thank you!!

The code:

```
class so {

    // Some object

}

class compareByIntValue implements Comparator<so> {
    public int compare(so o1, so o2) {
        // Comparing
    }
}

class StructureOnFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        RandomAccessFile objectsOnFile = new RandomAccessFile(FILENAME, "rw");

        fillWithObjects(objectsOnFile);
        quickSort(objectsOnFile, RecordSize, new compareByIntValue());
.
.
.
        }

    static <E> void quickSort(RandomAccessFile raf,
                              int RecordSize, Comparator<E> c) throws IOException {

        quickSort(raf, RecordSize, c, 0, (int) (raf.length() - RecordSize));

    }

    static <E> void quickSort(RandomAccessFile raf,
                                  int RecordSize, Comparator<E> c, int first, int last) {

        if (last > first) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(raf, RecordSize, first, last, c);
            quickSort(raf, RecordSize, c, first, pivotIndex - RecordSize);
            quickSort(raf, RecordSize, c, pivotIndex + RecordSize, last);
        }

    }

    static <E> int partition(RandomAccessFile list,
                                 int RecordSize, int first, int last, Comparator<E> c) {

        so pivot = new so();
        so tmp = new so();

        list.seek(first);
        pivot.readFromFile(list); // Reads first element into pivot
        int low = first + RecordSize; // Index for forward search
        int high = last; // Index for backward search

        while (high > low) {

            // Search forward from left
            list.seek(low);
            tmp.readFromFile(list);
HERE =================> while (low <= high && c.compare(tmp, pivot) <= 0 )
                low+=RecordSize;**
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really not expect a *generic method* taking a *generic comparator* to compare a *specific* type of object. Your method has parameter type of `Comparator<E>`, that would mean, it can accept any parameterized instance of `Comparator<T>`. And you are calling the `compare()` method on `so` objects. The compiler wouldn't like that. What would happen, if some other method passes a `Comparator<Integer>` to the method?

Having sorted out the issue, you need to figure out, whether you really need a generic method there? Wouldn't just changing the parameter type to `Comparator<so>` do your job? Have you created generic method intentionally, or you don't know what it really means? If it's the later one that is true, then don't write generic method. So, just change all your generic methods to non-generic, and change `Comparator<E>` to `Comparator<so>`. This will solve your issue, not considering any other issues.

Another approach would be to avoid creating a `Comparator` altogether, and make the `so` class implement `Comparable<so>`, and override and implement the `compareTo()` method there. And then you don't need to pass around any `Comparator` instances. Just replace `c.compare(tmp, pivot)` with `tmp.compareTo(pivot)`.

**On a serious note:** Please follow *Java Naming Convention*. `so` doesn't really make good sense as a class name. Give some sensible name, and make it to follow *camel-casing*, starting with upper-case letter.

Answer (score 2):

As Rohit Jain already noticed:

> You should really not expect a generic method taking a generic comparator to compare a specific type of object

For compiler to type check, you should change the signature of *partition* method to:

```
static int partition(..., Comparator<? super so> c)
```

By this you guarantee that the Comparator instance being passed will be able to handle objects of type **so**.